# How to make program stop on any action, or cancel savefiledialog?

Tags: c#, savefiledialog, cancellation

I have the following

```
SaveFileDialog xmlDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
xmlDialog1.Filter = "XML File|*.xml";
xmlDialog1.Title = "Save a XML File";
xmlDialog1.FileName = "RhodesConfigCalc.xml";
xmlDialog1.ShowDialog();
//garante que não foi premido o cancel
DialogResult res = xmlDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (res == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    MessageBox.Show("O ficheiro não foi gravado."); //translates into the file has not been saved
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

It's an attempt to patch up a few wrong message boxes, i want it to really cancel, and not do the actions ahead, hints?

edit: i forgot to mention this is on a closure method

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {}
```

Edit2: by this i dont mean closing the program, i mean "break the action", otherwise he will close without saving

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what you are asking. Also, why do you call `ShowDialog` twice?

Comment: Do you mean [`Application.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx) ?

Comment: No, i'm sorry, i mean not finishing the program, cause otherwise he will close without saving

Comment: It seems you want to show save file dialog, then check if user really saved the file or canceled the dialog. And you already done that here : `DialogResult res = xmlDialog1.ShowDialog();` . So how about simply remove the first call to `ShowDialog()`?

Comment: I did it because the first one is to show the dialog, the other is to store the result in "res".. I'm really a begginer on this :(

Comment: the 2nd one already did both, it show the dialog and store dialog return value in `res` when the dialog closed. Try it out. You don't need the first call as far as I can see

Comment: I fixed it guys, thanks for helping, I've just updated with a answer, the problem was not really canceling it, it was the behaviour ahead

Answer (score 0):

I corrected it removing the first showdialog

```
SaveFileDialog xmlDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
xmlDialog1.Filter = "XML File|*.xml";
xmlDialog1.Title = "Save a XML File";
xmlDialog1.FileName = "RhodesConfigCalc.xml";

//garante que não foi premido o cancel
DialogResult res = xmlDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (res == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
MessageBox.Show("O ficheiro não foi gravado."); //translates into the file has not been     saved
 e.Cancel = true;
}
```

But it was not enough, altough res would fail and the file not saved message would show up, some messages ahead were incorrect, (like file comparing), I had to set a double else if like this

```
                        if (resultadocomparacao2 == false) //IF compare fails, stops
                        { 
                            MessageBox.Show("A tabela não foi guardada correctamente.");
                            e.Cancel = true;
                        }

                        else if (res == DialogResult.Cancel) //If save is canceled, stops
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("O ficheiro não foi gravado."); //translates into the file has not been saved
                            e.Cancel = true;
                        }
                        else if (resultadocomparacao2 == true) //if compare gets his job done (Sucess)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("A tabela foi guardada com sucesso.");
                        }
```

I had to include all the 3 tests in the same if
Hope it helps